# one instance of application, platform independent, C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Is there a platform independent way in C++11 (boost is available) to make sure that only one instance of an application is started at a time? (I'd prefer not to run with the "file and (f)lock" method as it requires platform specific code, but I will do so if there is no better way.)

There is no (simple) other way like an unavailable port that I can use as a criterion in my scenario neither. And yes, I am aware of DOS problems - so no need to point those out.

I found the following similar question suggesting a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706960/3963625) with boost. 
The solution has two problems though:

- Minor: It seems a call to `shared_memory_object::remove("shared_memory");` is missing (in the case "the race was won"). But I am not really familiar with `boost::interprocess`, so maybe I am wrong?!
- Major: If the program crashes the shared memory is still existing and thus the next instance of the program will fail to start.

I also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/171213/3963625). No answer there that excites me. But it's a C++98 question so maybe with C++11 or boost there is a new/different way now?

Comment: Maybe this answer excites you? [How To Limit The Number Of Running Instances In C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545789/how-to-limit-the-number-of-running-instances-in-c/22545891#22545891)

Comment: @sehe: In that answer you mentioned that after _kill -9_ the semaphore needs to be removed "manually". Fair enough. What about in case of a program crash? I assume not every kind of crash can be handled with a signal?!

Comment: Yes, there is the usual ritual with [termination handlers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/atexit.html) and signal handlers. To be completely safe, you should probably detect stale IPC objects and handle that situation. It's about the robustness vs. convenience trade-off, for the large part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do [file locking in platform independent way with boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.file_lock).

[Lock a file or its own executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339606/412080).

Comment: Implemented it now in a helper class, small solution, works great! Thx!
`createFileIfNotExisting(filePath);

m_flock = boost::interprocess::file_lock(filePath.c_str());
const auto couldLock = m_flock.try_lock();
if(!couldLock) {
    throw Exception("Unable to lock file!");
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to a certain port, for example, using ASIO:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket sock(io);
    sock.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    sock.bind({boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), /*your port here*/}, ec);
    if (ec)
        std::cout << "Not mine\n";
    else
        std::cout << "It's mine\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If it succeeds, then it's the first application, otherwise it's already running.

Comment: There is at least 1 in 65535 chance that another application uses the same port.

Comment: Also using a port just for enforcing a single instance seems to be a waste (of course depending on the environment you're running in). Using other resources for this purpose (semaphores, files/file handles, ...) creates similar problems, but the number of available ports can't be increased. For other resources it can be possible to increase their number.